# Getting Runtime Error(SIGSEGV) on Code Chef, can't find out what's wrong in code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I know this type of question has been asked before but trust me I can't find a solution to this, I know its a invalid memory reference error, but I can't seem to find the cause of the error in my code.

I just tried my first problem on CodeChef, it was the **'Alien Chefs'** http://www.codechef.com/problems/DOWNLOAD and my submission was this,which gave me no errors on Dev C++ compiler, but pops a **Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)**

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

 int i,j,ctr,nr,toa,k,ng,q[100],p[100],na,l,sum[100],rc[100]={0};
 cin>>nr;
 for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
 {
    cin>>p[i]>>q[i];
 }
 cin>>ng;
 for(i=0;i<ng;i++)
 {
  cin>>na;
  ctr=0;
  fill_n(rc,100,0);
  for(j=0;j<na;j++)
  { 
    cin>>toa;
    for(k=0;k<nr;k++)
    {if(p[k]<=toa && q[k]>=toa)
     rc[k]=1;
    }
  }
  for(l=0;l<nr;l++)
  { if(rc[l]==1)
     ctr++;
  }
  sum[i]=ctr;   

 }
 for(i=0;i<ng;i++)
 cout<<"\n"<<sum[i];
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Because `nr` i.e `N` in problem can take values upto 100000.. But your `p` and `q` are of size just `100`.. In Competitive programming, read specifications very very carefully

Comment: Maybe you're right, I changed all the array sizes to '100000', but now I'm getting time limit exceeded.But I have two questions:
1. Why do you specifically state the value upto '100000' ? Shouldn't it be like '32767' ?
2. Is there something else I could do to get around this problem ? Because my code looks too simplistic when I compared it to other submissions which had used a lot of complicated functions and methods which I am unaware of as of now. Mine works totally fine and gives the right output.

Comment: @Yankee If u are getting TLE then u logic is wrong .. u should optimize your code ..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your code , Note that the values of N can be as large as 10^5

> 1 ≤ N ≤ 100000 (10^5)
>
> 1 ≤ Q ≤ 5000 (5 · 10^3)
>
> 1 ≤ K ≤ 20
>
> 1 ≤ Si, Ei, t ≤ 1000000000 (10^9)
>
> Si < Ei

and you have allocated only 100 elements for your array

> q[100], p[100], na,l, sum[100], rc[100]={0};

, so this is causing a out of bound exception at

```
for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
{
   cin>>p[i]>>q[i];//What will happen for i >= 100 ?
}
```

which is giving you a **SISEGV** ( segmentation fault ) ie you are trying to acess memory you didn't allocate/have no permission to access.

you may want to rethink your algorithm implementation,  check out   [Range Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree)  , Good Luck